# How to create hyperlink of table items by jaspersoft studio

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports

I can output pdf file which includes some tables by jaspersoft studio 6. But some of the table items need hyperlink setting. I have no way to implement it.

How can I add the anchor/hyperlink property to the table items?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of Jaspersoft Studio (JSS) double click the field that you want to make a hyperlink. It should open the table in the designer. Then single click the field you want to make a hyperlink.

I assume it is a textfield.

Look at the properties window and make that window WIDE. You should see hyperlink as a "tab" there. Click that and then set the hyperlink properties.